Setting conditional colors per task age
pic of table row
I'm developing a report using ssrs and report builder. My query and table are built and working.
I have a dataset with a field called Task_Age_Days - that calculates the number of days that have gone by since a part was created. My query line for this function is, DATEDIFF(day,aa.CREATED_ON,getdate()) 'Task Age (Days)'.
My table currently shows each part with the date is was created on and the number of days since in a long row format. I want it to highlight the days in red if its been over 60 days, yellow between 30-60 and maybe green if its been under 30.
I tried doing this in the color formatting but am not having luck. Here's what I did below.
Any tips?
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value >= 60, "Red")

It looks like you have a missing bracket for the Sum function.  You also need to provide a colour value for the false part of the IIf function.
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) >= 60, "Red", "Yellow")

If you want to produce three colours you could either use nested IIf functions like so:
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) >= 60, "Red", IIf(Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) >= 30, "Yellow", "Green")

But a Switch function might be easier to read:
=Switch(
    Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) >= 60, "Red",
    Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) >= 30, "Yellow",
    True, "Green"
)

The True value in the above example acts as an Else clause - the Switch function stops evaluating conditions when it reaches the first expression which returns True.  This avoids having to write an explicit logical test for the final condition, such as:
Sum(Fields!Task_Age__Days_.Value) < 30, "Green"

(thanks @Alan Schofield for the recommended edit)

I agree, switch is the recommended way to do this kind of thing, much easier to read. You may want to edit the answer to explain that the True acts as an ELSE because SWITCH stops when it find the first expression that evaluates to True.

thank you, this is so helpful. I was able to use the switch statement, and it worked perfectly. I don't have enough reputation to vote for your solution yet, but I did mark it as resolved!

Happy to hear it helped!

you can do this in the conditional formatting



